# Install Quickbooks Premier 2010

Tags: wine

I have been trying to get Quickbooks Premier 2010 to run in Wine. I can't do it. I am hoping that there may be someone who has been successful in installing various apps using Wine.

I am currently running windows 7 through virtual box, but I am disappointed with the performance. And it seems to be a little inconvenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this forum post:

http://community.intuit.com/posts/quickbooks-2010-multi-user-with-linux-server

The last known version of QB to work with Wine was 2004. A quick check at http://appdb.winehq.org/ did not give encouraging results either.

Here's hoping someone more knowledgeable comes along and contradicts me though.

Comment: if it says is doesn't work, making it work is a long and painful troubleshooting process.  Usually not worth the time.  If you pay yourself $10/hr to troubleshoot it is often resolved after you pay for XP a couple of times, if at all.  It's a better idea to install a vbox xp machine and install it that way.

Comment: For example, I have gotten some later versions of the adobe suite(not CS4 or CS5) working before.  It was such a painful experience and involved so much dll copy and over-ride that it wasn't worth repeating

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is what I've read but not in as much detail asnyou are saying. I think that what I need to do now is learn how to configure vbox so it runs smoothly.

Comment: @Keith a basic vbox more smoothly checklist would include - remove all un-necessary ubuntu components to reduce memory footprint, enable virtualization in hardware if available, tweak memory settings until you find optimum for the hw/sw combo you are running, enable graphics related accelerations in vbox if supported on your hw.  i know ppl that run seamless mode on login so they can have it look like a default XP desktop and fall back to linux when they use a family computer.